# binance api " Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset" error

Tags: c#, binance

I am trying to make a trading bot using the [Binance.Net wrapper library](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net).

Here is my code:

```cs
decimal price = client.FuturesUsdt.Market.GetMarkPrices(name + 
    "USDT").Data.FirstOrDefault().MarkPrice;
decimal amount = Decimal.Round((balance * lev * 98) / (price * 100), 4);

client.FuturesUsdt.ChangeMarginType(name + "USDT", 
    FuturesMarginType.Isolated);
client.FuturesUsdt.ChangeInitialLeverage(name + "USDT", lev);
client.FuturesUsdt.Order.PlaceOrder(name + "USDT", OrderSide.Buy, 
    OrderType.Market, quantity: amount);
```

> quantity=0.0018&recvWindow=5000&side=SELL&signature=664E64CF48C823D60AE93F1D4E14FEB98B829C3EBF13530B9C82B6F7636B2D20&symbol=btcUSDT&timestamp=1635599337350&type=MARKET

I get this error:

> Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset

What am I doing wrong or how do I fix this error?

Comment: I would recommend looking through the Issues papge on the repo, as it seems like a library-specific error. I can see there are already 6 issues mentioning this error: https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/issues?q=Precision+is+over+the+maximum+defined+for+this+asset
If those don't help you find the issue, your best chance is to open a new issue and I'm sure someone on the project can help you out.